# How do I force a memtable flush for every write?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

I would like to flush the memtable to disk after every update/write operation (or in any case, as frequently as possible). My sole purpose is to stress test the underlying disk using a production-level database software.

It seems like `memtable_cleanup_threshold` is the way to go, but it's deprecated, is there another way to accomplish this? How about `memtable_heap_space_in_mb` and `memtable_offheap_space_in_mb`? I'm no Java Programmer, which one should I tune without compromising the rest of the functionalities?

Comment: @Ken-White, the "Cassandra 4.0" in the title is completely relevant here because the answer is different if it relates to versions earlier than 4.0 so it makes sense to leave it in the title. Cheers! 

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez: It's redundant, as there is a Cassandra-4.0 tag on the question itself. It's only necessary in the title if there is no version-specific tag available, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely try setting both `memtable_heap_space_in_mb` and `memtable_offheap_space_in_mb` to a really low value.

Additionally, you can also configure `commitlog_total_space_in_mb`. If the occupied space goes above this property, it will cause more frequent flushes.

But since your goal is to stress-test the disk, my suggestion is to do the following:

- Configure both `data_file_directories` and `commitlog_directory` to be mounted on the same disk.
- Use [NoSQLBench](https://www.datastax.com/blog/nosqlbench) to stress test with heavy writes.

This way, you don't have to muck around with the memtable settings. Have a look at the [NoSQLBench Beginner's Guide](https://www.datastax.com/blog/a-beginner-s-guide-to-benchmarking-with-nosqlbench) blog post for details. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ErickRamirez, my testing framework is based on YCSB, I would rather keep on using that

Answer (score 0):

You also could just trigger a flush on the table by issuing `nodetool flush` or run the according JMX op after each write. However, Cassandra stores data distributed over many nodes and a flush is always a node bound operation. To find out which nodes you need to flush you would need to query the list of endpoints the written data is stored on (also available via JMX or with nodetool), otherwise you would need to flush all nodes.

While this is fine for testing purposes I would not recommend that for production.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me more about the jmx option?

Comment: You have a `void forceKeyspaceFlush(ks, cf)` operation provided by `org.apache.cassandra.db:type=StorageService` MBean which you can invoke with a keyspace name and optionally a table name to force a flush.